# Changing the units on google maps from metric to imperial

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have the following code:

```
<script>

      var rendererOptions = {
        draggable: false
      };
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var map;

      var England = new google.maps.LatLng(53.7415, 1.6860);

      function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: England
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map)
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
          computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
        });

        calcRoute();
      }

      function calcRoute() {

        var request = {
          origin: 'postcode',
          destination: 'postcode',
          waypoints:[{location: 'waypoint postcode'}, {location: 'waypoint postcode'}, {location: 'waypoint postcode'}],
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }

      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
          total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = total / 1000.
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%; height:100%"></div>
    <div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:30%;height 100%">
    <p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
    </div>
```

The map, shows an origin and destination, with certain waypoints along the way, using google api's direction service. The directions panel shows all distances in metric units. How do I change it, so that all distances are shown in imperial units i.e miles,feet?

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#UnitSystems)

> **Unit Systems**
>
> By default, directions are calculated and displayed using the unit
>   system of the origin's country or region. (Note: origins expressed
>   using latitude/longitude coordinates rather than addresses always
>   default to metric units.) For example, a route from "Chicago, IL" to
>   "Toronto, ONT" will display results in miles, while the reverse route
>   will display results in kilometers. You may override this unit system
>   by setting one explicitly within the request using one of the
>   following UnitSystem values:
>
> - `UnitSystem.METRIC` specifies usage of the metric system. Distances are shown using kilometers.
> - `UnitSystem.IMPERIA`L specifies usage of the Imperial (English) system. Distances are shown using miles.
>
> Note: this unit system setting only affects the text displayed to the
>   user. The directions result also contains distance values, not shown
>   to the user, which are always expressed in meters.