# Amending wordpress google router planner to mph

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am attempting to amend a wordpress plugin: Google Routeplanner, to display miles instead of km. From investigation I have to define unitSystem: UnitSystem.IMPERIAL under the following function: DirectionsService.route().

Unfortunately I am unable to get this working and wondering if anyone can shed some light on this please? The main .js file for the plugin is below. Thanks for any help!:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript");
?>

var icons = {
    main: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png',
        // (width,height)
        new google.maps.Size( 24, 38 ),
        // The origin point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
        // The anchor point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point( 12, 38 )
    ),
    start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_greenA.png',
        // (width,height)
        new google.maps.Size( 24, 38 ),
        // The origin point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
        // The anchor point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point( 12, 38 )
  ),
  end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
       // URL
       'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_greenB.png',
       // (width,height)
       new google.maps.Size( 24, 38 ),
       // The origin point (x,y)
       new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
       // The anchor point (x,y)
       new google.maps.Point( 12, 38 )
    )
};

<?php

echo '
var geocoder' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
var directionDisplay' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
var marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
var units' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';

if(typeof map_type_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' === "undefined" || \'\' == map_type_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ') {
    var a_map_type = \'ROADMAP\';
} else {
    var a_map_type = map_type_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
}

if(typeof zoom_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' === "undefined" || \'NONE\' == zoom_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' || \'\' == zoom_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ') {
    var a_zoom_control = false;
    var a_zoom_control_style = \'SMALL\';
} else {
    var a_zoom_control = true;
    var a_zoom_control_style = zoom_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
}

if(typeof pan_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' === "undefined" || \'true\' == pan_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ') {
    var a_pan_control = true;
} else {
    var a_pan_control = false;
}

if(typeof type_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' === "undefined" || \'NONE\' == type_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' || \'\' == type_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ') {
    var a_type_control = false;
    var a_type_control_style = \'DEFAULT \';
} else {
    var a_type_control = true;
    var a_type_control_style = type_control_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
}


function initialize' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '() {
    directionsDisplay' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
    geocoder' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var startplace' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.LatLng(52.52340510, 13.41139990);
    var myOptions' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = {       
            zoom: zoom_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ',
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId[a_map_type],
            zoomControl: a_zoom_control,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle[a_zoom_control_style]
            },
            panControl: a_pan_control,
            mapTypeControl: a_type_control,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle[a_type_control_style]},' . "\n";


        echo 'center: startplace' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '
    }

    map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '"), myOptions' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ');
    directionsDisplay' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.setMap(map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ');
    directionsDisplay' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.setPanel(document.getElementById("map_directions' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '"));

    google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL;
    codeAddress' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '(destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ');

}

function codeAddress' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '(address) {
    if (geocoder' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ') {
        geocoder' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.geocode( { \'address\': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                if(typeof alt_destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' === "undefined") {
                    var infowindow' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '
                    });

                    marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        icon: icons.main,
                        title: destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '
                    });
                } else {
                    var infowindow' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: alt_destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '
                    });

                    marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ' = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        icon: icons.main,
                        title: alt_destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '
                    });     
                }

                marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.setMap(map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '); 

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ', \'click\', function() {
                    infowindow' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.open(map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ',marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ');
                });

            } else {
                alert("' . 'Could not find the target location. Please be more specific!' . '");
            }
        });
    }
}

function calcRoute' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '() {
    var start = document.getElementById("fromAddress'. $_GET['plan_id'] . '").value;
    var end = destination_' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ';
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.setDirections(result);
            marker' . $_GET['plan_id'] . '.setMap(null);
            var leg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
            makeMarker( leg.start_location, icons.start, start );
            makeMarker( leg.end_location, icons.end, end );
        }
    });
}

function makeMarker( position, icon, title ) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map' . $_GET['plan_id'] . ',
        icon: icon,
        title: title
    });
}
';

?>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404066/changing-the-units-on-google-maps-from-metric-to-imperial

Comment: Hi Marthijn, thank you for your reply! I am unable to understand how to amend the markup within the javascript to specify the imperial units and/or amend the call to longitude (which causes the units to be outputted in meters initially)